# .NET convert Datetime to format Sortable date/time pattern ("s");

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, format

Im working with VS2008, .NET and C#, and I need to send to one of our clients a DATETIME variable.

The problem is that they want the Date in the format Sortable date/time pattern ("s").

When I get the actual datetime, it is a Datetime object. When I format it to the given format is now a String object, and it has the format I want. But after that I can't create a Datetime object from that formatted String with the same format, because it always returns it to the original Datetime format.

More specific:

```
DateTime currTime = System.DateTime.Now; //(the format is "13/08/2010 09:33:57 a.m.")

String date = String.Format("{0:s}", currTime);// (wanted format "2010-08-13T09:33:57")

DateTime newDate = DateTime.Parse(date);// (original format again "13/08/2010 09:33:57 a.m.")

IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("", true); //(Invariant Culture)
String format = "s";                        
DateTime fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, culture); // (original format again "13/08/2010 09:33:57 a.m.")
```

Is there a way of getting a Datetime object with the desired format, or Datetime objects use a given format, and you can't format them to the equivalent string formats?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I think you are getting confused. A `DateTime` object itself is not formattable, it is essentialy just a numeric value (number of ticks since `DateTime.MinValue` or whatever it is).

You can convert a `DateTime` object into a `string` *representation* in whatever format you like, but you aren't changing the actual `DateTime` object.

Comment: Would the downvoter be so kind as to explain what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I have no idea, take a +1 from me to counteract it.

Answer (score 13):

A `DateTime` is just a number.  It has no intrinsic "format".  It is only rendered into a format when converted to a string.  Hence, whenever you need a DateTime as a string, you have to specify what format you want it in.

```
String date = String.Format("{0:s}", currTime);
```

This can be shorted a bit to :

```
String date = currTime.ToString("s");
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I typed `DataTime` *twice* ??  See what happens when I don't have Intellisense...

Comment: After executing following syntax
String date = currTime.ToString("s"); 
output will be
2014-01-29T11:25:29

Now can you save this dateTime format into a variable having Type DateTime ?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use a `DateTime` value in a place where it needs to be turned into a string (e.g. in `string.Format()`), C# will generally call the `.ToString()` method. The `DateTime` type declares a `.ToString()` method that has the format you don’t want.

However, `DateTime` has additional methods, including `.ToString(IFormatProvider provider)` and `.ToString(string format)`.

Therefore, you can probably achieve what you want if you replace every use of a `DateTime` variable in the relevant string-like context to one that calls the appropriate `.ToString` overload, for example:

**Instead of**

```
var message = string.Format("The parcel was sent on {0}.", currTime);
```

**use**

```
var message = string.Format("The parcel was sent on {0}.", currTime.ToString("s"));
```